# Trouble replacing multiple occurences of pattern on the same line

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a regular expression in Perl that works on text files that are a mix of text and account numbers.  What I would like to do is reformat the account numbers. I am running across an issue with using `.*` to match on either side of the account numbers when there is more than one match on a given line.  I have done some searching and couldn't find any answers so I am hoping that someone could explain to me what is wrong with my regex so I can avoid this pitfall in the future.

```
while(<>) {

    s/(.*)\b([0-9]+)\b(.*)/$1xxx\-$2$3/g;
    print;
}
```

The `xxx-` are going to be replaced by account identifiers but till I get it working I have just `x`'s.

The issue I am having is that only the last occurrence get's replaced not all occurrences.

For example with a simple sample line:

```
First Part 223456 Third Part Fourth Part 113456 Fifth Part Sixth Part
```

I would expect:

```
First Part xxx-223456 Third Part Fourth Part xxx-113456 Fifth Part Sixth Part
```

But I only get:

```
First Part 223456 Third Part Fourth Part xxx-113456 Fifth Part Sixth Part
```

I have it narrowed down to the `.*`  as the issue if I include other metacharacters in the capturing group it works but I have no guarantees as to what's in the files so I need to match everything.  It only happens when there are multiple account numbers on the same line; if the account numbers appear on multiple lines it works fine.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If account numbers are just going to be numbers, just do this:

`s/\b(\d+)\b/xxx-$1/g;`

And if they will always be 6 numbers, be more specific: `s/\b(\d{6})\b/xxx-$1/g;`

Comment: Thanks for your help I think I was getting confused about how the replacement worked and was trying to rebuild the whole thing instead of just replacing the parts that matched.

Answer (score 2):

`(.*)` consumes all the characters in the input, it then has to start backtracking: giving one character back and testing if the next pattern matches and if not, it gives back another character and checks the match, character by character.

So by putting a greedy universal match as your first expression, you're actually *asking* the engine to only find the last match. You might not have known you were asking for this, but you were.

Generally, when processing regex, you have to think about the data: "How would I identify this pattern in a file. Very likely, "one-or-more digits" just doesn't cut it for an account number, so *specify* the pattern you want to match to the best of your ability to specify it. 
Then you can be sure that if something matches your pattern, it is likely what you want. By the way, the word boundary specification was a *good* start.

If you need *exactly* six digits, then specify exactly *six* digits.

Another reason that you should not have to specify `(.*)` as part of a match is that, from the looks of it, you are doing what you think you need to do to keep the other parts of the line in their place. But, Perl only replaces the matched section with the replacement. You *never* need to specify anything but the part you want matched.

So, assuming that your account numbers are 6 digits wide, this is all you need.

```
 s/\b(\d{6})\b/xxx-$1/g;
```

One last point. If for some reason your regex would have found you the first match, specifying `(.*)` *after* the pattern, *guaranteed* that you you only find one match per line, and the `/g` would not apply, because it makes the full match equal to the line of input.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is greedy matching `(.*) which in your case will match everything up until the last ([0-9]word boundary)`. I think you can just turn this off and you should be fine`(eg. s/(.*?)//g)`.

Here's a small example:

```
while(my $line = <$fh>) {
    $line =~ s/(.*?)\b([0-9]+)\b(.*?)/$1xxx\-$2$3/g;
    print $line;
}

OUTPUT:
First Part xxx-223456 Third Part Fourth Part xxx-113456 Fifth Part Sixth Part
First Part xxx-223456 Third Part Fourth Part xxx-113456 Fifth Part Sixth Part
First Part xxx-223456 Third Part Fourth Part 
First Part xxx-223456
```

Comment: (.*?) is unnecessary beginning and end of a regex

Comment: the reqex will just move along the starting position if it can not match a a particular place so (.*?) is not needed. The area affected by the substitution will shrink and since all this substitution is doing with the captures is replacing them where they where they are unnecessary.

Comment: Wow, I can hardly follow that above statement. I think you're trying to say that @Lone Shepard above answer is correct. If that's what you're trying to say, then I agree that it seems that he's only worried about the \d+. However, this question seems very *scholastic* so I was answering the question at hand: "Why is this greedy match failing?"...

Answer (score 0):

One way using negative look-behind and another positive look-ahead:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\d)(\d+)(?=\D|$)/xxx-$1/g' <<<"First Part 223456 Third Part Fourth Part 113456 Fifth Part Sixth Part"
```

It yields:

```
First Part xxx-223456 Third Part Fourth Part xxx-113456 Fifth Part Sixth Part
```